# getting access denied or wrong path for paths with spaces

Tags: python, path

I have a function that should work as windows file explorer and I'm facing a problem accessing 'C:\Users\mr.five\My Documents\'. Technically, anything with spaces can't be accessed or path is wrong. The first try was using double quotes before and after the path and the error appears as 'WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:\Users\mr.five\My~\"/*.*'' and when I remove the double quote, I get this 'WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\mr.bogus\My Documents/*.*'

I know for a fact that I'm running this script under admin privilege so it isn't the problem. I have read alot about it and some people are complaining about ntfs conjunction.

any help will be appreciated

the whole code is

```
    import os
    import json


    class file_act:
       def __init__(self,xpath):

          self.path = xpath
          print self.path[0]


      def path_to_dict(self):
          path = self.path
          print path
          d= {}
          d['dirs'] = []
          d['files'] = []
          # d['metadata']= []
          for f in os.listdir(path):
              fof=os.path.join(path, f)
              if os.path.isfile(fof):
                  d['files'].append({'file':f, 'path':fof
                  # "metadata": os.stat.st_mtime(os.path.join(path, f))
                  })
              if os.path.isdir(fof):
                  d['dirs'].append({'dir':f, 'path':fof})
          d['mainfolder'] = os.path.dirname(path)
          return d


commandcls = file_act('C:\Users\mr.five\My Documents')
info= commandcls.path_to_dict()
# data2=pickle.dumps(info)
print info
```

Comment: I get WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\mr.five\\My Documents/*.*'

Comment: Just try this, insert \ , `file_act('C:\Users\mr.five\My\Documents')` whenever there is space in folder name

Comment: This is will consider as a different path I assume as I'm getting the error connot find the path specified

Comment: i used abspath and to validate it the path as path = os.path.abspath(self.path) and then it works for all path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. My solution was managing more effective the double quote. You can try:
C:\Users\mr.bogus"My Documents"
or if the problem is with the environment variables of the system you can try:
SPARK_HOME ---> C:\My Documents\Spark
then you can put in the settings
"%SPARK_HOME%"

I hope that it can help you